# Whitespace and specific characters when using operator >>

Tags: c++

I have a custom String class that contains a char array, and I need to overload the >> operator for this class. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do two things.

1 - Read the user input until a ; is reached

2 - Include whitespace from user input

I cannot use namespace or c++'s built-in string. Unfortunately that rules out the use of getline and any of the convenient find functions (I think it does, anyway?). Some things I have tried:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& output, String& input) {
    output >> input.str;
return output;}
```

This works but only up until the first whitespace, after which point it stops reading the user input.

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& output, String& input) {
while (output != ';') {
    output >> input.str;
}
return output;}
```

An istream I guess isn't equivalent to the user input so you cannot compare it to a char like I tried to in my while loop.

So, my questions are, how does one read input until a specified character is encountered, and how does one include all whitespace when using >> ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it's unusual to have an **input** stream named `output`.

Comment: Read one character at a time, and test if it matches the specific character.

Answer (score 0):

The global `operator>>` for string/character input stops reading when it encounters whitespace, so it is not worthwhile to implement your custom `operator>>` in terms of the global `operator>>`.

You ruled out use of `std::getline()`, but you can use [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead.  Like `std::getline()`, it also has an optional `delim` parameter (the default is `'\n'`), and will read characters - including whitespace - until the delimiter or EOF is reached.

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& input, String& output)
{
    return input.getline(output.str, yourmaxstrsize, ';');
}
```